# Checking whether two Django querysets have any items in common

Tags: django, orm

I have two querysetd in Django. How can I efficiently check whether they have any elements in common, i.e. if there exists any element that is in both querysets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check if an intersection exists:

```
(qs1 & qs2).exists()
```

Answer (score 2):

In [Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#intersection), simply `queryset1.intersection(queryset2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use query sets like sets:

```
intersection = queryset1 & queryset2
```

`intersection` will be the intersection of the two querysets